# Multiple URLs pointing to same tab in hook_menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hook-menu

Here's a basic menu structure I'm working with:

```
function events_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['events'] = array(
        'title' => 'Current Events',
        'access callback' => true,
        'page callback' => 'page_event',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
      $items['events/current'] = array(
          'access callback' => true,
          'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
          'weight' => 1,
      );      
      $items['events/regions'] = array(
          'title' => 'Event By Region',
          'access callback' => true,
          'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
          'weight' => 2,
      );
      $items['events/range/%/to/%'] = array(
          'title' => 'Current Events by Range',
          'access callback' => true,
          'page callback' => 'page_event_range',
          'page arguments' => array(2, 4),
          'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
          /* Don't want this to be a tab.
             I want it to activate the default tab */
      );

    return $items;    
}
```

The URL (and default tab) `events` displays some data.  I'd like the URL `events/range/%/to/%` to filter the data based on the passed URL parameters.

The hook_menu above works, but I don't want `events/range/%/to/%` to be it's own tab.  When you use the filtered URL, I want the default tab, Current Events, to remain active -- to give the illusion that you're looking at the same page as `events`, only filtered.  Can multiple URL's point to the same tab?

I guess I could handle the url parameters manually with `arg()` in the `events` page callback, but this seems hacky.  Isn't there a way to do this using hook_menu?

**Edit (stated more clearly):**
Normally there are two tabs Current Events and Event By Region at the URLs `events` and `events/regions`.  I want a hidden (callback only) url at `events/range/%/to/%`.  But when you visit it, I want the two tabs to remain visible and Current Events active - as if we'd never left that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to accomplish what you want only with hook menu. What you could do it use [`menu_set_active_trail`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/6) to make drupal make it look like the users is looking at the `/events` page.

The above method might only work for Drupal 7

For Drupal 6 you could alter `$_GET['q']`. This can, however, conflict with some modules like purl or globalredirect. This is not a pretty solution but it works. The best place to do this would be in the a custom module using `hook_init`.

Comment: I see how this function can change my breadcrumb trail, but I don't see how that applies to my problem: displaying two tabs when at the filtered url, with the active one being the default tab.

Comment: @AK: The active trail is not only used for breadcrumbs but also to determine which menu item (tab) should be shown active. If you actually tried it out you would see that it works.

Comment: @AK: I've done this myself in D7 to circumvent a bug in Drupal core. I haven't actually tested this in D6, and the menu system hasn't changed that much. But of cause there's a chance that this just wont work in D6.

Comment: After seeing a usage in [user.pages.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/user_page/6), I got this working with `menu_set_active_item()` -- which I see is just a wrapper for altering `$_GET['q']`

Answer (score 0):

Use MENU_CALLBACK instead of MENU_LOCAL_TASK, and the tab will disappear. Then set the current menu item to 'events' like so (might only work in hook_init, but you can try  it in the page callback too:

```
$item = menu_get_item();
$item['href'] = 'events';
menu_set_item(NULL, $item);
```

Comment: Hmm, not getting this to do anything in either hook_init or page callback... looking deeper at menu_set_item...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'context' Module. You can set path pattern you want for the active menu. Check out this [quick video demo.](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2008/apr/09/context-ui)